# Java Double in array

Tags: java

Sorry if this is a super noob question.

From what I have read it seems I can't store a double in an array. Is there some work around that I can use ?  That will allow me to get the values into the array without changing the values. I would also need to compare against an external variables stored as doubles.

Comment: Why this shouldn't work? Never heard about this... Can you show, how you use this?

Comment: -1; it would have taken about 30 seconds to just test this before asking the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using an `ArrayList` you have to use the class `Double` instead of primitive type `double`

```
ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

or use a simple array

```
double[] arr = new double[10];
```

Comment: @user1351037 It also doesn't answer the question you actually asked. You asked about arrays. This is about lists.

Answer (score 0):

You were reading something way too wrong

```
double[] doubleArray = {1.1, 1.234567, 2.0,5.5}; //initialize double array to hold those values
double[] anotherArray = new double[3]; //initialize another array to hold 10 doubles
anotherArray[0]=5.5; //set the value for first elements
```

Answer (score 0):

In java any object or primitive data types (ex: int, double, short etc) can be assigned in an array. Yeah the restriction could be there in specialized JVM like embedded one's for example javacard where memory is limited and have to be utilized optimally.